# Why is @JVMStatic annotation necessary for Kotlin main function?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, compiler-construction

Recently started learning Kotlin. I noticed an interesting behaviour when declaring the main function in Kotlin. It uses a @JvmStatic annotation even when in an object class. I looked around and did not find a relevant post.

```
object Main {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Why does the main function in Kotlin require a @JvmStatic annotation?

Coming from a Java and Scala background, it seems redundant and unnecessary, so I am curious what the background context and decision making was that made Kotlin adopt this convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@JvmStatic` is ***not*** required if you declare `main` as a top-level function. That is, if the entirety of your Kotlin source file is:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

You do not need `@JvmStatic` in this case - all top-level functions are translated to a static method in Java, in a class called `XXXKt` by default, where `XXX` is your Kotlin file name.

Note that for parameterless top-level `main`s in Kotlin, the compiler actually generates a proper Java `main` that takes `String[] args`, and delegate to your Kotlin function.

```
// the Kotlin main gets converted to something like this...
public static void main$1() {
    // your kotlin code here...
}

// A proper Java main generated by Kotlin
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main$1();
}
```

You *do* need `@JvmStatic` when you put the `main` method inside an `object`, because `object`s are translated to a singleton class in Java. All the members in the `object` are non-static by default.

```
object MyObject {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    }
}
```

is translated to something like this:

```
public final class MyObject {
    private MyObject() {}

    public static final MyObject INSTANCE = new MyObject();

    public void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

When you do `MyObject.main(...)` in Kotlin, it is actually `MyObject.INSTANCE.main(...)` in Java. Obviously, such a `main` method cannot be used as the entry point of a Java program, because it is not static.

Comment: That's interesting. Any recommended resources on understanding Kotlin to Java/JVM compilations?

Comment: @SomebodyNEW Some of that is described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html), but not how `main` functions translate though. In general, you can just look at the bytecode output. You can do that in IntelliJ in View -> View Bytecode.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin has no direct equivalent of Java static methods. The closest it has are top level functions (ones not in any class). For these to be callable in Java, they are automatically compiled as a Java static method in a generated class named after the file with “Kt” appended.

Kotlin `object`s have no direct equivalent in Java. An `object` is an actual instance of a class. Its functions are just regular, non-static methods. A Kotlin object can be accessed via a generated `INSTANCE` static field in Java. This simply returns the class instance of the Kotlin object. Through it, you can access its methods.

`@JvmStatic` tells the compiler to compile the function as static. The reason this isn’t automatically done is that it puts a bunch of restrictions on the function that normally wouldn’t exist in Kotlin so it’s therefore necessary to require an opt-in. For instance, it cannot reference or call anything specific to the class instance, such as functions/properties defined in its superclass, and it cannot override anything.